# Search a word in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have an ajax result as follow:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "AABB",
      "text": "AABB"
    },
    {
      "id": "BBCC",
      "text": "BBCC"
    },
    {
      "id": "CCDD",
      "text": "CCDD"
    },
    {
      "id": "DDEE",
      "text": "DDEE"
    }
   ]
}
```

by that I load it to select2 using ajax below:

```
        $("#timezone").select2({
            ajax: {
                url: "/User/Timezone",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                type: 'GET',
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term, // search term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    var arr = []
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        arr.push({
                            id: value.id,
                            text: value.text
                        })
                    })
                    return {
                        results: arr
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            minimumResultsForSearch: 20
        })
```

I try to search the word CCD, of course I expect the pointer brings me to the CCDD line, but it keeps staying on the first data, did I miss something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems I can't reproduce it, it should not show results that do not match your input.

```js
$("#timezone").select2({
  data: [{
      "id": "AABB",
      "text": "AABB"
    },
    {
      "id": "BBCC",
      "text": "BBCC"
    },
    {
      "id": "CCDD",
      "text": "CCDD"
    },
    {
      "id": "DDEE",
      "text": "DDEE"
    },
    {
      "id": "AABB1",
      "text": "AABB1"
    },
    {
      "id": "BBCC1",
      "text": "BBCC1"
    },
    {
      "id": "CCDD1",
      "text": "CCDD1"
    },
    {
      "id": "DDEE1",
      "text": "DDEE1"
    },
    {
      "id": "AABB2",
      "text": "AABB2"
    },
    {
      "id": "BBCC2",
      "text": "BBCC2"
    },
    {
      "id": "CCDD2",
      "text": "CCDD2"
    },
    {
      "id": "DDEE2",
      "text": "DDEE2"
    },
    {
      "id": "AABB3",
      "text": "AABB3"
    },
    {
      "id": "BBCC3",
      "text": "BBCC3"
    },
    {
      "id": "CCDD3",
      "text": "CCDD3"
    },
    {
      "id": "DDEE3",
      "text": "DDEE3"
    }
  ],
  escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
    return markup;
  },
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  minimumResultsForSearch: 20
})
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<select id="timezone"></select>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```